# Returning Value from nested Promise.alls

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, hexo

I'm asking this question because I might have a fundamental misunderstanding of how bluebird's `Promise.all` works:

**I'm having trouble understanding how I return the value from nested, dependent, `Promise.alls`**.

I *can* get the desired result to display in console though. (you can see the data that I'm trying to return in the commented `console.log`).

For context, I'm writing a [Hexo](https://hexo.io/) plugin that gets a collection of related blog posts then returns five of them.

Each promise depends on the data returned from the previous promise.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')
var _ = require('underscore')

hexo.extend.helper.register("related_posts", function (site) {
  var site = site
  var post = this.page
  var tags = post.tags
  var title = post.title
  var tagList = tags.map(function(tag){
    return tag.name
  })

  // get 5 posts from each group and add them to a posts array
  var PostsArray = []

  Promise.all(tagList).then(function(items){
    items.forEach(function(theTag){
      PostsArray.push(site.tags.findOne({name: theTag}).posts.sort('date', -1).limit(25).toArray())

      Promise.all(PostsArray).then(function(posts){
        var thePosts = _.flatten(posts)
        var finalListOfPosts = []

        thePosts.forEach(function(post){
          if(post.title != title){
            finalListOfPosts.push(post)
          }
        })

        Promise.all(finalListOfPosts).then(function(posts){
          var relatedPosts = _.first(_.shuffle(posts),  5)
          // MY DATA IS CONSOLE.LOGGED AS I WOULD EXPECT
          // BUT HOW DO I RETURN IT?
          console.log(relatedPosts)
        })

      })
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: Can you please show the link to the documentation of `site.tags.findOne`, if there is a solution or not depends on if that function is async or not.

Comment: Thanks for your help @t.niese - unfortunately that function isn't in the docs as far as I can tell. I found it [here](http://1pixelout.net/2015/09/18/writing-hexo-template-helpers/)

Answer (score 2):

Promises work by `return` value. Just like regular functions. If you `then` a promise the value you return from the then is the value the outer promise will assume:

```
var p = Promise.resolve().then(() => { // resolve creates a new promise for a value
  return 3; // can also return another promise here, it'll unwrap
});

p.then(alert); //alerts 3
```

For this, if you have a nested chain (you never have to nest more than 3 levels) - you need to `return` from it all the way in order to access the value:

```
 return Promise.map(tagList, function(name){ // map is a bluebird utility
   return site.tags.findOne({name: name}).posts.sort('date', -1).limit(25).toArray();
 }).
 then(_.flatten). // flatten the list
 filter(function(item){ 
   return item.title !== title; // filter - also a bluebird utility, like Array#filter
 }).then(function(posts){
   return _.first(_.shuffle(posts), 5);
 });
```

Comment: Does this meet the "get 5 posts from each group" requirement (where presumably a "group" is a tag's-worth of posts)?